# Is it possible to expand a macro into several elements?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I want a macro `my-macro` which can expand to `1 2 3` rather than `(1 2 3)`, so that

```
(list (my-macro) 4 5) -> (1 2 3 4 5)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I am quite convinced that not, as to explode a list you usually use @ but this requires that it is within list to explode into. I cannot find any reference that explizitly states that though.
If you got a specific problem on your heart you want to solve with this question, you might want to post that one.

Comment: @Sim I want to expand the macro as args of a function call. Now I have to use `(apply #'foo (append (my-macro) (list 4 5)))` instead of `(foo (my-macro) 4 5)`. The latter is much more simple and clear.

Comment: @Sim It seems that a read macro can not do this, right?

Comment: `apply` will take as many lists or elements as you give it, so no need to `append` them. Other then that, I'd probably just go with a function that curries the arguments you want to pass in this way or something like that.

Comment: @wvxvw `apply` will take as many arguments as you give it, and the _last_ must be a list.  So you can do `(apply 'frob bar1 bar2 (list bar3 bar4))` and it's the same as `(frob bar1 bar2 bar3 bar4)`, but by the same process, `(apply 'frob (list bar1 bar2) (list bar3 bar4))` is equivalent to `(frob (list bar1 bar2) bar3 bar4)`.  SaltyEgg would still need to append the argument lists.

Comment: @SaltyEgg use apply, it actually is more clear as everybody knows what it does instead of your (actually impossible) macro. http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm#apply

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor well, that's what SaltyEgg has right now: some number of arguments followed by the list, so no need to append them. Although I didn't know what the rules exactly was, I think it might be the rule of how `&rest` collects the arguments (is it?)

Comment: @wvxvw It's called a [spreadable argument list designator](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#spreadable_argument_list_designator).  Unless I've misunderstood something, SaltyEgg has `(1 2 3)`, and wants something equivalent to `(list 1 2 3 4 5 6)`.  `(apply 'list '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))` will produce `((1 2 3) 4 5 6)`, not `(1 2 3 4 5 6)`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Oh, then there was one more thing I was thinking about: `(multiple-value-call #'list (values 1 2) 3 4)` which is not a macro, but maybe OP will find it useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, macros cannot expand to more than one value. The typical thing to do when you need a macro to expand to multiple pieces of code is to wrap the return value in a `progn`.

In your example in the comments, it looks as if you are using macros not as syntactic abstractions, but as cheap-and-cheerful function optimizations, the usual response to that is "please don't do it, it is wrong and doesn't actually do what you want".

Answer (score 4):

No.

Neither a macro nor a read macro can do that in Common Lisp.

The only solution if you really need this is to write a full reader yourself where you don't use `read` at all (the problem is that `read` will recursively call itself, and not your version).

A full compliant reader is quite a complex thing to do, but it can be simple if you only need a subset of the features and you don't need to use it for example to read Common Lisp code written by others.