# Can I make a macro that expands into more than one value?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

Is there a way to define a racket macro `foo` so that

```
(list 1 (foo 2 3) 4)
```

expands into

```
(list 1 2 3 4)
```

?

Comment: In case any future readers find this while looking for a Common Lisp answer, see [Is it possible to expand a macro into several elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18886612/1281433) (the answer is “no” in Common Lisp, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers have mentioned, you cannot have a macro expand into more than one value, and have that spliced into the calling context. But you can do something similar using quasiquotation.

Assuming your macro is adapted to return a list instead, you can do this (for your given example):

```
`(1 ,@(foo 2 3) 4)
```

Example (tested in Racket):

```
> `(1 ,@(map sqrt '(2 3)) 4)
'(1 1.4142135623730951 1.7320508075688772 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not possible (and seems unlikely to change in the near future).
Here's one [thread discussing this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/dIytiJmYGTU/Q9TJUPxc4cAJ). See in particular the answer by Matthew Flatt:

> allowing splicing of results in function-call
>   subexpressions would break equivalences that are currently exploited by
>   macros and the compiler.