# How do I expand inner macros before the outer ones?

Tags: macros, lisp, scheme, racket

Say I have the following macro:

```
(define-syntax-rule (qq x) '(1 x))
```

Can I make something that looks like `(qq (qq 2))` expand into `'(1 (1 2))` instead of `(1 (qq 2)` ?

The reason I say "looks like" is because so far the only [hint I found](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-macros#H-1nxb3vk) suggests that inside-out macro expansion is tricky so I wonder if whats the saner way to do get my desired end result.

My original motivation has to do with Racket's [parser generator library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/parser-tools/index.html): to create a grammar the library provides a `parser` macro that looks like this:

```
(define my-parser (parser
  (start start) (end EOF)
  (tokens value-tokens op-tokens)
  (error (lambda (a b c) (void)))

  (grammar
   (start [(numbers) $1])

   (numbers [(numberx) (reverse $1)])
   (numberx [() empty]
            [(numberx NUM) (cons $2 $1)])
  )
))
```

My grammar has lots of boilerplate that I would like to abstract away. For example, I would love to be able to define some sort of `list-rules` abstraction that would let me write write something similar to

```
(define my-parser (parser
  (start start) (end EOF)
  (tokens value-tokens op-tokens)
  (error (lambda (a b c) (void)))

  (grammar
   (start [(numbers) $1])

   (list-rules NUM numbers numberx)
  )
))
```

However, if `parser` gets to expand first it will treat `list-rules` itself as a non-terminal instead of expanding it into the real non-terminals (`numbers` and `numberx`).

Comment: Please invest a few minutes learning how to [format Lisp code](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`local-expand`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html?q=local-expand#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._local-expand%29%29), though I admit I haven't spent the time to understand the second part of your question enough to know whether it's the right thing to use.

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax (qq stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ x) 
     (with-syntax ([y (local-expand #'x 'expression '())])
       #'`(1 ,y))]))
(qq 2)
(qq (qq 2))
(qq (qq (qq 2)))
```

=>

```
'(1 2)
'(1 (1 2))
'(1 (1 (1 2)))
```

Comment: local expand didn't work. I tried making an ["expanding-parser" macro](http://pastebin.com/5TKrPrCh) that local-expanded all productions inside the "grammar" argument but 1) it would attempt to expand things that shouldn't be expanded (the error could complain about "start" being unbound) and 2) my "list-rules" would need to expand into two list items and I don't think you can do that with macro expansion...

Comment: Now that I think of it, if this were just a matter of producing a list or syntax object with the structure I want I could just use quasiquotation (with `,@` or `#,@` for the "list-rules") but I have no idea how to define `my-parser` from that.

Comment: `local-expand`'s 3rd argument is a list of stop identifiers so you can control how much expansion happens. Does adding `start` to this list fix the error?

Comment: Passing `#f` as the third argument to local-expand solved the first problem but now I get a `let-values: cannot bind identifier tainted by macro expansion in: numberx` error when I try to use the `list-rules` macro. Additionally, there is still the issue that I would eventually need list-rules to expand into 2 non-terminals,  instead of just one, something that [I don't think is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194884/can-i-make-a-macro-that-expands-into-more-than-one-value)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 2 syntax rules, with the more general rule first; also not the use of the quasiquote and unquote operators so that the inner form can be evaluated:

```
(define-syntax qq
   (syntax-rules ()
     ((_ (x ...) ...)  `(1 ,(x ...) ...))
     ((_ x)            `(1 x))))
```

such as

```
-> (qq x)
'(1 x)
-> (qq (qq x))
'(1 (1 x))
-> (qq (qq (qq x)))
'(1 (1 (1 x)))
-> (qq (qq (qq (qq y))))
'(1 (1 (1 (1 y))))
```

This is also composable:

```
(define-syntax qq
   (syntax-rules ()
     ((_ (x ...) ...)  `(1 ,(x ...) ...))
     ((_ x)            `(1 x))))

(define-syntax hh
   (syntax-rules ()
     ((_ (x ...) ...)  `(2 ,(x ...) ...))
     ((_ x)            `(2 x))))
```

such as

```
-> (qq (hh x))
'(1 (2 x))
-> (hh (qq x))
'(2 (1 x))
```

Comment: Looks like this solves the simplified problem with the recursive macro but I can't seem to understand how this can be used to expand arguments to an existing macro from a library.

Comment: @missingo My understanding is that this depends on how the library macro is designed.

Comment: sure. what do I do if the library macro does *not* do your trick?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could have the macro check for the *shape*:

```
(define-syntax qq
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(qq (qq x)) (list 1 (qq x))]
    [(qq x)      (list 1 x)]))
```

The good news is that this works "recursively":

```
(qq 2)           ; => '(1 2)
(qq (qq 2))      ; => '(1 (1 2))
(qq (qq (qq 2))) ; => '(1 (1 (1 2)))
```

But it will also work even if something other than `qq` is supplied:

```
(qq (+ 1))       ; => '(1 2)
```

If that's a problem for your intended use -- if you'd like that to be flagged as an error -- you could do it like this instead:

```
(define-syntax (rr stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ (rr x))
     (cond [(equal? 'rr (syntax->datum #'rr))
            #'(list 1 (rr x))]
           [else (raise-syntax-error #f "Expected rr" stx #'rr)])]
    [(_ x)
     #'(list 1 x)]))
```

Same results for the examples, except the last now gives a syntax error:

```
(rr 2)           ; => '(1 2)
(rr (rr 2))      ; => '(1 (1 2))
(rr (rr (rr 2))) ; => '(1 (1 (1 2)))
(rr (+ 1))       ; =>
; src/scheme/misc/so-syntax.rkt:27:5: rr: Expected rr
;  at: +
;  in: (rr (+ 1))
```

*Update*: The second version could be written a bit more cleanly using [`syntax-parse`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse.html):

```
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))
(define-syntax (rr stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ ((~literal rr) x)) #'(list 1 (rr x))]
    [(_ (_ x)) (raise-syntax-error #f "Expected rr" stx #'rr)]
    [(_ x) #'(list 1 x)]))
```

Comment: Looks like this solves the simplified recursive macro problem but I can't see how this would apply to my original problem :(